# Create, populate and access a multi-dimensional array in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array

I have the data structure (given below), can you please let me know how to populate and also to access the elements in the simplest form anytime I want. Which is the best way to implement, like Hash of Hashes or Array of Arrays or anything else ?  There won't be too many elements in the array, the only problem is the its a multi-level kind of array

```
%Array = (

    'Item0' => {
        'Name' => 'Item0_Name',
        'Attribs' => {
            'Attr1' => {
                'Name' => 'Attr1_Name',
                'Num'   => 'Attr1_Num'
            },      
            'Attr2' => {
                'Name' => 'Attr2_Name',
                'Num'   => 'Attr2_Num'
            }       
        }       
    },

    'Item1' => {
        'Name' => 'Item1_Name',
        'Attribs' => {
            'Attr1' => {
                'Name' => 'Attr1_Name',
                'Num'   => 'Attr1_Num'
            },      
            'Attr2' => {
                'Name' => 'Attr2_Name',
                'Num'   => 'Attr2_Num'
            }       
        }       
    }

);
```

Comment: [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Calling a hash Array is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The official resource for this is the Perl Data Structure Cookbook ([`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)).

For the data shown, it seems that an array of hashrefs is sufficient since the keys shown in the OP are simply a stringified index. The same comment applies for 'Attribs':

```
my @array = (
              {
                  'Name' => 'Item0_Name',
                  'Attribs' => [
                                  {
                                      'Name' => 'Attr1_Name',
                                      'Num'  => 'Attr1_Num'
                                  },      
                                  {
                                      'Name' => 'Attr2_Name',
                                      'Num'   => 'Attr2_Num'
                                  }       
                               ],
              },
              {
                  'Name' => 'Item1_Name',
                  'Attribs' => [
                                  {
                                      'Name' => 'Attr1_Name',
                                      'Num'  => 'Attr1_Num'
                                  },      
                                  {
                                      'Name' => 'Attr2_Name',
                                      'Num'   => 'Attr2_Num'
                                  }       
                               ],
              },
           );
```